# Android studio - Failed to resolve (gradle) Uber library

Tags: android, uber-api

In my Android application, I want to add Uber facility to users so that I looked the following [library](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk). So that I added the `compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.1.0'` in my main module's (Main application) build.gradle file. It gives me following error when sync the gradele

```
Failed to resolve: com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.1.0
```

I have some other libraries referenced to the application.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':payPalDemo1')
    compile project(':uberLibrary')
    compile project(':bSLibrary')
    compile project(':pullToRefresh')
    compile project(':androidmapsutils')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/cardio.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/UserFormValidation.jar')
}
```

Please help me to resolve this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your gradle file

```
repositories{
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the portion of your `build.gradle` file that you have included you only have the `mavenCentral()` repository specified within the `buildScript` block. In order to make that repository accessible outside of that context you should include a block such as the following to the root level of your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

In addition, you have not actually included the line `compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.1.0'` in the file copied in your question.

Ultimately, your `build.gradle` should include the following:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this SDK is designed to work with Android SDK 16. so `minSdkVersion` should be 16 or greater